# How do I a specific element from an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I receive an array from a `Session.get()`, that I then save to a `clickedImages` variable, as per code below:

```
var clickedImages = Session.get('clickedImages'); 
console.log("clickedImages is: " ,...clickedImages);
```

The code above yeilds:

```
Object {imageId: "ikrbCDuttHrwkEcuv"} Object {imageId: "e72HwJhHyjDhDogJK"} Object {imageId: "GttzCQLzMeqjJP4Ae"}
```

To enable me to do further processing, I am only interested in the **"imageId" property**, that's to say, the desired output is:

```
"ikrbCDuttHrwkEcuv", "e72HwJhHyjDhDogJK", "GttzCQLzMeqjJP4Ae"
```

How do I achieve this?

I have tried and failed achieving this with: `console.log("clickedImages is: " ,...clickedImages.imageId);`

Comment: `clickedImages.map(i => i.imageId)`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C

Comment: "element" refers (usually) to either an HTML element, or a member of an array. `imageId` is a **property**.

Comment: @torazaburo Actually in my code, the imageId isnt a property, but rather an element which holds a specific value of interest. Sorry that in my initial posting i referred to imageId as a property